# Run Oracle Form Application from a JSP File

Tags: oracle, jsp, jakarta-ee, oracle10g

I have a complete customized application made on Oracle Forms (10g) and I have .fmb and .fmx files, now problem which I am facing is I have to open the Oracle Form Application from my JSP page (which is used to login the user). My JSP page is just a simple page which I have placed it in path

```
[C:\DevSuiteHome2\forms\j2ee\formsapp\formsweb]
```

and I run it from browser as

```
[http://localhost:port/forms/index.jsp].
```

How can I start my application from this JSP page? Your help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To call an Oracle Form
You need to start the Weblogic first,  then you can call the form by an URL, you can test it in browser as example:

http://machine_name:port/forms/frmservlet?&form=form_name.fmx

Example: 
http://ibmcygp:7001/forms/frmservlet?&form=MAIN.fmx